# Multiple Checkbox Groups with corresponding hidden content

Tags: javascript, checkbox, filtering

Basically I want to do the exact opposite of this script example:

http://jsfiddle.net/n3EmN/

On this example, where the 'content' is listed, I want that area completely blank, until the user makes there selections.

Is it possible to edit the JavaScript to do this?

Ex. Code:

```
$(function(){
    $('.flowers-wrap, .continents-wrap').delegate('input[type=checkbox]', 'change', function() {
        var $lis = $('.flowers > div'),
            $checked = $('input:checked');  
        if ($checked.length) {                          
            var selector = '';
            $($checked).each(function(index, element){
                if(selector === '') {
                    selector += "[data-category~='" + element.id + "']";                  
                } else {
                    selector += ",[data-category~='" + element.id + "']";
                }
            });                        
            $lis.hide(); 
            console.log(selector);
            $('.flowers > div').filter(selector).show();               
        } else {
            $lis.show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So, if I understand you want to hide the div and show it when a selection is made, is that right?

Comment: FYI: As of jQuery 3.0, `.delegate()` has been deprecated. It was superseded by the `.on()` method since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged

Comment: Ok thank you. And yes, that is exactly right. I'm am needing some sort of script to do just that. Hide the div w/associated content, until a selection is made. And like this example, I do have 3 groups/or sections of checkbox options.

Comment: Well, I got it to work. First thing I did was add the class "flower" to the CSS and set the display to none.. that "blanked" out the content so it isn't seen.  It actually worked, and it was re-hiding the content when unchecked... all, but the first on I clicked on... when deselected, it would not re-hide itself. Then I changed the end of the script from $lis.show(); to $lis.hide(); It all seems to work fine now. I got lucky. And if I replace delegate with "on", it doesn't work at all. Not sure if that's what you meant for me to do?